# Trying to prevent RStudio from crashing after opening Rmarkdown with memory intensive graphic

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I made the mistake of trying to visualize a network graph (using `visNetwork`) with a million edges.  Needless to say, it crashed my computer.  Now though, whenever I open the rmarkdown file I was working out of, Rstudio displays all the execution of all my chunks.  I've tried disabling display in the global options but this hasn't been effective.

The other wrinkle here is that I never actually saved my Rmarkdown file, so it's just when I open up the project it displays what I was last working on.

Any ideas for how to stop Rstudio from displaying the chunks when I open it?

Comment: In the project directory, look for `knitr` cache files/directories and remove the offending ones. Then you might want to edit the actual `.Rmd` file externally (using Notepad or NPP or Sublime or emacs or vim or ...), comment out the problem area, and saving it. (Caveat: not a frequent RStudio user, so it's a stab.)

Comment: Also look for .Rdata or .Rda files- if you're saving and restoring your environment that could be trying to reload the graph object

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem in my situation here is that I never actually saved the file--after I tried to plot the graph it crashed.  It's opening back up to the file when I click on the project that I was working out of.